# Protractor not finding element- all looks correct

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

Protractor is not finding this element.....it's driving me crazy. Any ideas why? The element does exist...I verified it in the dev console.

```
<download
  path="api/backup_jobs/errors.csv"
  params="errorsFilter"
  class="header-action">
  Download Filtered CSV
</download>

element(By.css('[path^="api/backup_jobs"]')).getAttribute('path');

element(By.css('download[params["errorsFilter"]')).getAttribute('path');
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? You are using a `getAttribute` function on element but not using the result of it anywhere. Can you explain a little. Thanks

Comment: does it matter? it's out of the context of not finding the element

Comment: Well it does matter as to what you write in your question. If you want complete set of questions, here they are - What do you mean its not finding the element? Does it give any error? or its not getting the attribute of the element? Is it hidden or out of view? Are you using proper element locators? Is the element locator unique? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this selector is correct:

```
element(By.css('download[params["errorsFilter"]')).getAttribute('path');
```

You've probably meant instead:

```
$("download[params=errorsFilter]").getAttribute('path');
```

Also check that the element is not inside an `iframe` - if it is, you would need to switch into the context of the frame using [`switchTo()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.switchTo), before searching for the element:

```
browser.switchTo().frame("frame_name_or_id");
```

And, if this is a "timing" issue, you can explicitly [wait for the element to be present](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions,
    elm = $("download[params=errorsFilter]");

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm), 5000);  // wait up to 5 seconds

expect(elm.getAttribute('path')).toEqual("api/backup_jobs/errors.csv");
```